# Mouse & Keyboard press combination keystroke for Mouse click - Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

i wannna be able to press Middle Button for simulating Shift+Middle Button or Left Button+Middle Button function (both make same thing) with AutoHotkey. 
this is for panning with middle button in Sketchup software.
i tried many things but none of them worked for me.

for example i wrote that:

MButton::
send, {Shift & MButton down}
keywait, MButton
MButton Up::
send, {Shift & MButton Up}
Return

this function has to work like X-Mouse Button's: during function. when i press the button it has to press the other keys simultaneously. and release in the same way.
so, what can i do?

Comment: Can you show the code you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it!

the solution:

MButton::Send {Shift Down}{MButton Down}
keywait, MButton
MButton Up::Send {Shift Up}{MButton Up}
return